# How do I normalize a Python matrix with one CSV column?

Tags: python, csv

I have a matrix where ONE COLUMN is a CSV, like this:-

```
matrix = [
    [1,"123,354,23"],
    [2,"234,34,678"]
]
```

How do I normalize this, so I get one row for each value in the CSV column, i.e. so that it looks like this:-

```
[
    [1, 123],
    [1, 354],
    [1, 23],
    [2, 234],
    [2, 34],
    [2, 678]
]
```

I'm open to using numpy or pandas.

Note, in my specific case there are many other non-CSV columns too.

Thanks

Comment: Is `matrix` a variable which contains lists?

Answer (score 2):

In the example you gave, this will do it:

```
matrix = [
    [1,"123,354,23"],
    [2,"234,34,678"]
]

import ast

expanded = [
    [ index, item ]
    for index, rowString in matrix
    for item in ast.literal_eval('[' + rowString + ']')
]
```

For your other "non-CSV" cases it depends on how they are formatted.  Here, `ast.literal_eval` was a good tool for converting your apparent standard (comma-separated string) into a Python sequence that the variable `item` could iterate over.  Other conversion approaches might be needed for other formats.

That produces a list of lists exactly as you specified. `pandas` is a good tool to use from there though.  To then convert the list of lists into a `pandas.DataFrame`, you could say:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(expanded, columns=['index', 'item']).set_index(['index'])
print(df)
# prints: 
# 
#        item
# index      
# 1       123
# 1       354
# 1        23
# 2       234
# 2        34
# 2       678
```

Or, if by "many other non-CSV columns" you just mean an arbitrary number of additional entries in each row of matrix, but that the last one is still always CSV text, then it could look like this:

```
matrix = [
    [1, 3.1415927, 'Mary Poppins', "123,354,23"],
    [2, 2.7182818, 'Genghis Khan', "234,34,678"]
]

import ast

expanded = [
    row[:-1] + [item]
    for row in matrix
    for item in ast.literal_eval('[' + row[-1] + ']')
]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(expanded).set_index([0])
```

Comment: Perfect! Your last example gives me what I wanted. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix contains couples of the form (*first*, *text*), you can write:

```py
result = [
    [first, int(rest)]
    for first, text in matrix
    for rest in text.split(",")]
```

Or, without comprehension list:

```py
result = []
for first, text in matrix:
    for rest in text.split(","):
        result.append([first, int(rest)])
```

Comment: Note that this makes the strong assumption that the CSV values are always ints (never, for example, floats or strings).

Comment: You can use the float function instead of int.